# Парадокс Монти Холла - не реализовать

Tags: теория-вероятностей

Пытаюсь запрограмировать компьютер на победу с помощью [парадокса Монти Холла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Моя задача однако угадать генерируемое число из пяти чисел.
То есть компьютер генерирует любом число = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
И другая функция угадывает это число.
Игра повторятся большое количество раз и по статистике моя функция должна привести к победе.
Я попыталась следовать логике, описанной теорией вероятностей.
Однако, к сожалению, мой код не приводит к выигрышу. 
Может быть кто-то может подсказать в чем ошибка.

```
val choice1 = random.nextInt(5)

var shown1:Int;
do shown = random.nextInt(5) while (shown1 == choice1)

var choice2: Int
do choice2 = random.nextInt(5) while ( choice2 == shown1 || choice2 == choice1)

var shown2:Int
do shown2 = random.nextInt(5) while (shown2 == shown1 || shown2 == choice1 || shown2 == choice2)

do guess = random.nextInt(5) while (guess == choice1 || guess == shown1 || guess == choice2 || guess == shown2)

return Guess(guess)
```

Comment: Укажите в метках к вопросу что за язык программирования.

Comment: А что значат переменные у вас? Что такое `choice1` и `shown2`? Кстати, а у вас получается нужный результат для классического Монти Холла с тремя дверями?

Comment: Не надо редактировать вопрос добавляя решение, пометки решенный и т.п. Добавьте ответ. А последнюю правку откатите.

Answer (score 6):

Вопрос решен, всем спасибо. 
Готовый вариант на java:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Monty{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int switchWins = 0;
        int stayWins = 0;
        Random gen = new Random();
        for(int plays = 0;plays < 32768;plays++ ){
            int[] doors = {0,0,0};//0 is a goat, 1 is a car
            doors[gen.nextInt(3)] = 1;//put a winner in a random door
            int choice = gen.nextInt(3); //pick a door, any door
            int shown; //the shown door
            do{
                shown = gen.nextInt(3);
            //don't show the winner or the choice
            }while(doors[shown] == 1 || shown == choice);

            stayWins += doors[choice];//if you won by staying, count it

            //the switched (last remaining) door is (3 - choice - shown), because 0+1+2=3
            switchWins += doors[3 - choice - shown];
        }
        System.out.println("Switching wins " + switchWins + " times.");
        System.out.println("Staying wins " + stayWins + " times.");
    }
}
```